# Import 3d model with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to learn three.js and i've been following their documentation. I can't manage to import an object from blender. What am i doing wrong here? I have the scene, camera, renderer and loader.

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.131.3";
import { GLTFLoader } from "path/";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const loader = new GLTFLoader();

loader.load(
  "path/object.glb",
  function (gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Comment: Three.JS is often pretty good at giving helpful messages in your browser's web inspector console tab. (F12) Attaching those if there are any will help others diagnose your problem. The Network tab may also show helpful information. Hosting online what you've created would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLTFLoader cannot be imported from `"path/"` because that’s a folder. You need to point to a .js file that contains the loader code.

(Also, it would be helpful if you post any errors you see in the console)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was reffering to path as the directory i will be using for the loader(it was the correct directory), but i was using the wrong GLTFLoader.

Comment: But `import {GLTFLoader} from “path/“;` doesn’t make sense. It can’t import the loader if you’re pointing to a folder. It needs to point to a JavaScript file.

Comment: You are right, i actually switched to using <script src="link to package"> for it to work, but now when i am trying to use other packages (which are not hosted anywhere) i am unable to do so using <script src="TrackballControls.js">. It gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: THREE.TrackBallControls r is not a constructor.

Comment: That’s a different question altogether. If my answer solved your original problem, you could accept or vote on it. But it sounds like you don’t understand how importing works. I recommend you look up tutorials on it so you don’t run into these problems for every module your app needs.